# How to add pictures to the left menu of Android TV?

Tags: java, android, android-tv, android-menu, leanback

Trying to add pictures to the left menu on your Android TV.
I was able to add a picture to the top right.

[image: Screenshoot]

But I don't understand how it is adding to the left.

```
setBadgeDrawable(getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your custom TitleView.

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QFHIfQy8_Wc) is a great video on customizing the components of the leanback library (Custom TitleView part starts at 05:48)

and [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/leanback-showcase/blob/master/app/src/main/java/android/support/v17/leanback/supportleanbackshowcase/app/page/CustomTitleView.java) is the source code of the CustomTitleView used in Google's Leanback Support Library Showcase App for Android TV

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I added the image to the left menu. I had one more question.How I can narrow the menu area like Netflix? @burakk

Comment: You should create a new question with details. What do you want to achieve, what have you tried so far, etc.